# How to perform a series of animations using promises

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am making a Rubik's cube animation using three.js. I am currently trying to make a function that shuffles the cube.

I have already made functions that animate a single move(like rotating right face 90 degrees clockwise). Now, to shuffle the cube I randomly select 5 moves and call the function corresponding to that move. I want to perform these moves(animations) ONE AFTER OTHER. To do that I am using promise chaining. However, they are happening at the same time.

```
function shuffle(){
    let promise = Promise.resolve();
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        promise = promise.then(randomMove);
    }
}
function randomMove(){
    //this function randomly selects a move and calls the corrosponding function
    //MOVES is an array of functions that animate a move
    //cubeAnimator is a class that stores these functions
    let side = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
    let turns = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
    MOVES[6*turns+side][1]();
}
//this is sample of a functions that rotate a side of cube
function r1(){
        let cubiesToRotate = cube.getCubiesByVID([].concat(cube.RIGHT_CENTRAL_CUBIES).concat(cube.RIGHT_CORNER_CUBIES).concat(cube.RIGHT_EDGE_CUBIES)); // this is list of cubies to rotate
        let group = new THREE.Object3D();
        for(let cubie of cubiesToRotate){
            group.add(cubie);
        }
        scene.add(group);
        this.rotate(group,new THREE.Vector3(-1,0,0),90*Math.PI/180,0);
    }
function rotate(cubies,axis,angle,total){
        console.log(axis);
        if(total <= angle){
            total+=0.05;
            cubies.rotateOnAxis(axis,0.05);
            renderer.render(scene,camera);
            requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                cubeAnimator.rotate(cubies,axis,angle,total);
            });
        }
    }
```

Every function uses the following logic.

Change the position of the cubies

call renderer.render

call requestAnimation with the same function as the callback, if rotation is not complete

I guess I can use setTimeout to add a delay between to moves. But I feel that's not the right way to do it. So please give other suggestions.

Comment: please share the `cubeAnimator.rotate` implementation.. it is crucial for answering your question

Comment: @ymz it is the rotate function I have provided.

Comment: `cubeAnimator.rotate` from this line `cubeAnimator.rotate(cubies,axis,angle,total)` should have a callback / promise handler when it is done... I need api reference or complete code of `cubeAnimator` in order to understand what's going on

Comment: @ymz cubeAnimator is just an object that has r1 and rotate. For the sake of simplicity I have copied r1 and rotate out here. I have edited the question from MOVES[6*turns+side][1].call(cubeAnimator) to MOVES[6*turns+side][1](). There are other functions as well such as l1, f1 and so on. But they are just copy of r1 with different parameters to getCubiesByVID and rotate. So I am not listing all of them here.

Answer (score 0):

To do movements one by one you need to create new Promise after previous is resolved. Your promises are resolved immediately so it happens at the same time.
You can fix that by:

```
function shuffle(){
    let promise = Promise.resolve();
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        promise = promise.then(_ => new Promise(resolve =>
        randomMove();
        resolve();
      ));
    }
}
```

A batter way to handle stream of movements is to use rxjs. 
And you could do it like that:

```
function shuffle(){
    const movements = []
    for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      movements.push[randomMove]
    }
    from(movements).pipe(concatMap((callback) => callback()) 
}
```

concatMap will execute next randomMove after the previous has completed.